# Why is this RPM "uninstallable"?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

Sometimes when I ask Zypper to install something, I will get a message similar to this:

```
Problem: foo-tools requires foo-lib, but this requirement cannot be provided

Problem: foo-tools requires foo-lib, but this requirement cannot be provided
  uninstallable providers: foo-lib.7.31.13.x86_64
Solution 1: do not install foo-tools
Solution 2: break foo-tools by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

Why the hell does Zypper think that the RPM which I purposely gave it for this exact reason is an "uninstallable provider"? What does this message *mean*? Is the RPM file unreadable? Wrong arch? Wrong version? *What is it upset about??*

Comment: Read the first line again. Or the second one. The RPM is readable, correct arch, good version, but it has a dependency that is not available.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `foo-tools` except that it wants `foo-lib`. Given that the RPM file for `foo-lib` is sitting right there, why is it an "uninstallable provider"?

Comment: What is the exact requirement of `foo-tools`? Version? Also, what are the exact names and versions of the packages installed (`foo-lib`) and the one you want to install (`foo-tools`). (BTW, it's really called "foo", because if it's I will look for the one called "bar")

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `foo-lib` itself had unmet dependencies. Adding these fixed the problem.

But the question is... why didn't Zypper *say* that was the problem? Usually if a dependency problem happens, it tells you about the specific package that couldn't be found. Why did I get this opaque "uninstallable provider" message?

Answer (score 1):

RPM keeps a database of installed files (for example binary executables and shared libraries) in the system.

Some software, such as foo-tools, need other software (such as foo-lib) to function properly. This dependency information is decided by the RPM packager.

If you haver foo-lib and foo-tools available as RPM files, but neither are installed, you can provide them both (all) on the command line to RPM (or in a zypper-equivalent way), to make RPM see that all the dependencies will be satisfied. Another option is to install the prerequisite packages first.

If foo-lib in turn has its own dependencies they too must be satisfied. It they are not, foo-lib is not an installable provider of foo-lib.

Unrecommended: make sure the prerequisites are met by some other means (install the required things manually, perhaps from source, and force Zypper to ignore the dependencies.
Doing this will cause problems later, so don't do it.

Comment: Neither RPM is currently installed. I put all the required RPMs into a folder and told Zypper to install all files in that folder. Usually this works, but sometimes I get messages like the above. I'd like to know why exactly.